# Parallax landing pages and the affect on SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines, marketing

Are there any unique concerns which need to be addressed to optimize SEO in a parallax scroll landing page?

Page will initially load from the bottom and scroll upwards through 5 sections which include multiple parallax layers, HTML5 embedded video content, sliders, and a social media integration targeting inbound traffic from a television commercial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main SEO hit you may take here is related to page load time. You can use [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to optimize the speed of your page. But basically you want your page to load as fast as possible for SEO purposes. **Google won't be able to tell that you're using the parallax effect** specifically, but they will be able to tell you're using large images/videos. It is important to realize that googleBot does not use javascript, so any changes to the DOM made after the initial page load via javascript will not be recognized by Google.