# Best practice for scroll-up web page

Tags: seo, javascript

As was pointed out in a question asked earlier, Google will not recognize when the DOM is altered via JavaScript after initial page load to start at the bottom and scroll up rather than down.

[Parallax landing pages and the affect on SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56923/parallax-landing-pages-and-the-affect-on-seo)

Is there an alternative better way that can be considered for achieving the same affect and maintaining the most optimized and correct search results and SEO score?

Comment: Most parallax websites that I've seen start from the top and you scroll down.  What is the advantage of scrolling from the bottom?

Comment: The content warrants it, and I try not to make choices based on what other people are doing.

Comment: How much content is on the page?  Is it a book's worth or an article's worth?

Comment: More like an infograph which starts with a flower growing from the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invert your results. On DOM load, you use js to invert it again. So, crawlers will read from top to bottom, but when page loads, it will have inverse position.

This fiddle illustrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gx5B7/1/